# Trying to apply classes on a click event using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript and have used the primary post about how to toggle classes from here: [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript) but for some reason my code is not executing like I would expect it to. The code is placed in the bottom of an HTML file.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.arrow').addEventListener('click', function() {
if (this.hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')) {
    this.addClass('glyphicon-chevron-left');
    this.removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
    }

if (this.hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-left')) {
    this.addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
    this.removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-left');
    }
}, false);

});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery uses `on` to add events; not `addEventListener`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a click listener and use **[`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** instead of those `if` clauses:

```
$('.arrow').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-left');
});
```

Or more succinctly

```
$('.arrow').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-left');
});
```

Comment: And even `$(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-left")`

Comment: @JuanMendes i am aware of that. I though it would be more clear this way.

Comment: @martynas Now the OP is also aware of that ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, so I don't need to wrap this code in anything to make sure the document is ready? EDIT: Nevermind I figure it out, thanks again.

Comment: @WarGravy Yes, you should still make sure the document is ready. This snippet is just what needs to be changed from your original script

Answer (score 2):

Just use the jQuery click event.

```
$('.arrow').click(function() {
    if (this.hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')) {
        this.addClass('glyphicon-chevron-left');
        this.removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
    }
    if (this.hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-left')) {
        this.addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
        this.removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-left');
    }
});
```

if you want to add the event specifically with an event listener you would probably have to select the actual element instead of the jQuery object: `$('.arrow')[0]`